# Each loop round progressively slows down my SDL game

Tags: c, sdl

I am working on a little [sokoban](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) game, using the SDL 1.2 library. The most interesting possibility of this program is to move a character on a map. However, I am facing some strange slowing-down problem which I fail to find the reason of.

I simplified the code so it is not too long.

Here is the loop that makes the character move:

The followings correspond to the blocks of the game (each case of the map) and its position on the screen. For example, `bloc[3]` is a pointer to the surface corresponding to the 4th case of the map.

```
SDL_Surface *bloc[256] = {NULL};
SDL_Rect pos_bloc[256];
```

---

```
while (on == 1)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                        on = game_menu(screen);
                        refresh_screen(screen, bloc, pos_bloc, zone);
                        break;
                    case SDLK_UP:
                        if (zone[m - 16] == ' ') // m is the position of the character on
                                                 // the map. As the map is 16 blocks large,
                                                 // and the position in the map is registered
                                                 // in a string, m - 16 means: 1 case up.
                                                 // m + 16 means: 1 case down.
                            m = swap_2blocs(screen, bloc, pos_bloc, zone, m, -16, "up.bmp");
                        break;
                    case SDLK_DOWN:
                        if (zone[m + 16] == ' ')
                            m = swap_2blocs(screen, bloc, pos_bloc, zone, m, 16, "down.bmp");
                        break;
                    default:;
                }
            default:;
        }
        SDL_Flip(screen);
    }
```

Whenever the keys up or down are pressed, it calls a function that swap 2 surfaces: it frees both `SDL_Surface` pointers concerned and then reallocates some memory for another surface:

```
int     swap_2blocs(SDL_Surface *screen, SDL_Surface *bloc[256], SDL_Rect pos_bloc[256], char zone[257], int m, int n, char *character)
{
    SDL_FreeSurface(bloc[m]); // The surface pointed to by `bloc[m]` is freed
    bloc[m] = SDL_LoadBMP("empty_space.bmp"); // `bloc[m]` now points to another surface
    SDL_BlitSurface(bloc[m], NULL, screen, &pos_bloc[m]);
    zone[m] = ' '; // zone is the string that contains informations about each map block
                   // ' ' stands for an empty space, 'M' stands for the character
    m += n;
    zone[m] = 'M';
    SDL_FreeSurface(bloc[m]); // The surface pointed to by `bloc[m]` is freed
    bloc[m] = SDL_LoadBMP(character); // `bloc[m]` now points to another surface
    SDL_BlitSurface(bloc[m], NULL, screen, &pos_bloc[m]);
    return m;
}
```

There are several things to be known:

1. The problem randomly appears 1 out of 3 times.
2. After 15-25 events (key up or key down), the slowing-down effect begins to be felt. After something like 30 events, it starts being really slow (there are around 300ms between the moment when the key is pressed, and the moment when the characters move on the screen).
3. It does slow down more than these approximative 300ms.
4. When the problem appears, going back to the main menu (which implies to free all the surfaces pointed to by each pointer contained in `bloc`) and starting a new game doesn't reset the speed of the game. To reset it, the program must be exited and then launched again.

I would like to understand this mysterious behaviour: where does it come from? What is happening?

Comment: I don't see the code how `bloc` and `m` are managed from the character move loop. It may be you have a bug that is causing more surfaces to be created without freeing them. Then memory swapping could be causing your performance slow down.

Comment: Do you know which function slows down up the screen refresh up to 300ms? I mean, I would add time stamp to measure `SDL_Flip`, `swap_2blocs`. Secondly, is SDL_KEYDOWN repeated every time you press the arrow key?

Comment: @wyc actually, any of them can cause the problem, I tested it. I feel like it has something to do with the action of freeing a pointer and then making it point to another surface, but I can't figure out what's wrong. About time stamp, I don't know yet how to master time in SDL so I may have to do without it for now. About SDL_KEYDOWN, it seems to me that it is repeated every time the arrow key is pressed, since the function `SDL_WaitEvent` is in a `while` loop, which means that after an arrow key is pressed and the instructions that follow are done, the program will wait for the next input.

Comment: @jxh ye that's what I had to check, the first version of my program used no `SDL_FreeSurface`, but in the current version I think that all pointers to surfaces are correctly freed before being reused, and yet the problem persists.

Comment: I do not know SDL, but the only thing that stands out is `SDL_WaitEvent` and what `event` can be. If `SDL_WaitEvent` just blocks (or checks a descriptor like `pslelect`) I don't see a problem, but if `event` can be more than just keystrokes and you are registering a WaitEvent over and over again, I could see that slowing things down. Like I said, I don't know SDL, but just looking at the code, that was something that stood out.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the function `SDL_WaitEvent` waits for an event to occur, even though this notion of "waiting" is not defined more precisely in the wiki or in the doc. The program must receive an event input (a key pressed or a movement of the mouse, for example) in order to continue. `SDL_WaitEvent` fills the informations corresponding to the event that occurred in `event`, which is a structure, declared as follow: `SDL_Event event;`.